# Is there a way to query the billing usage using python, when granted the Monitor Account privilages?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to query snowflake billing information and summarize it in a Jupyter Notebook.

I am currently using Snowflake-SQLAlchemy and the python-snowflake-connector to connect to Snowflake and query databases. I want to query credit usage by different users/warehouses on the account. I have been granted Monitor Account privileges so I can see this information in the UI, however, I cannot see how I can query this information directly.

I have tried queries such as the one below, however since I do not have AccountAdmin, I cannot query this schema directly.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import snowflake.connector

query = """
select start_time::date as usage_date,
       warehouse_name,
       sum(credits_used) as total_credits_used
from warehouse_metering_history
where start_time >= date_trunc(month, current_date)
group by 1,2
order by 2,1;"""

result_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

The expected result is a data frame containing data similar to the data seen under account, billing & usage. This is a table listing users and credit usage over time. Currently I am not able to return any of this information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you're logging on with the correct role (the role that has been granted the monitor account privs). If you don't specify which role you are logging on as in your python script then Snowflake will use your `default_role` and that may not have the correct privileges.

Also you can try to fully-qualify the `warehouse_metering_history` table so that it contains the database and schema of the table like the following:

```sql
select start_time::date as usage_date,
       warehouse_name,
       sum(credits_used) as total_credits_used
from snowflake.account_usage.warehouse_metering_history -- Here fully qualify the table 
where start_time >= date_trunc(month, current_date)
group by 1,2
order by 2,1;
```

Try running the same query through the web interface and see what you get.